# How to take a tuple and make a new column depending on another column in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset that contains **ID** for all managers and employees, I have **job_title** and the **job_ID** the goal is to make a new column differentiating between who is a manager and who is not, using the JOB_ID and creating a new column **Emp_Type**.
Here is an example:

```
ID      Job_Title          Job_ID 
101     Sales Supervisor   10110
102     Sales Rep          10111
103     Support Manger     10112
103     Tech Support       10113
104     Tech Consultant    10114
105     Consulting Assist. 10115
```

And this is what I want:

```
ID      Job_Title          Job_ID     Emp_Type
101    Sales Supervisor    11010         M
102    Sales Rep           10111         E
103    Support Manager     10112         M
104    Tech Support        10113         E
105    Tech Consultant     10114         E
106    Consulting Assist.  10115         A
```

I have tried using a dictionary function at first but realized that if there were any additional values added to the column I would have to add in manually:

```
manager_dict = {(10110,10112):'M'}
emp_dict = {(10111, 10113,10115): 'E'}
assist_dict ={10115:'A'}
```

Any ideas on the most optimal way to do this?

Comment: What do you want the behavior to be if new values are added to job_title?

Comment: @Burrito If a new job title is added ands doesn't watch that job id then i would want to flag it

Answer (score 0):

You can use (assuming pandas is being used):

```
d = { 'Supervisor': 'M',
       'Rep': 'E',
       'Manager': 'M',
       'Support': 'E',
       'Consultant':'M',
       'Assist.': 'A'
       }
 
df['Emp_Type'] = df['Job_Title'].map(d).fillna('U')
```

.map looks up the Dictionary and uses the appropriate value. Unknown values are flagged as 'U'